# How do I bind a listbox to the property of a property using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to populate a listbox with a bunch of serial data. I am saving the data to an ObservableCollection named SerialData (SerialData is type SerialMessage, a class that contains a bunch of data including 2 strings, time stamp and Message that I want to display). The ObservableCollection is a member of the DataCollector class. In the MainWindowViewModel I have declared the DataCollector and made it public. In my MainWindow the datacontext is set to MainWindowViewModel.

I want to bind the SerialData to a listbox on the MainWindow where I display the timestamp and message. I have tried several methods of binding the path to the SerialData but it does not show up in the listbox. I have confirmed that SerialData is updated correctly.

Is it possible to bind to the property of a property and display it's members?

My Code snippets:

SerialMessage class

```
    ...
    /// <summary>
    /// The time the message was received
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime TimeRecived
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The message on the serial bus
    /// </summary>
    public String Message
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    ...
```

Mainwindow

```
...
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
...
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Name="MessageList" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DC.SerialData}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeRecived, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Margin="10,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    ...
```

MainWindowViewModel

```
    ...
    /// <summary>
    /// Instance of data collector
    /// </summary>
    public DataCollector DC
    {
        get
        {
            return m_dataCollector;
        }
    }
    ...
```

DataCollector Class

```
    ...
    /// <summary>
    /// All of the Data recived on the serial Bus as it comes in
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<SerialMessage> SerialData
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to customize the look of your list-box.
So with this code, what is getting displayed currently in the list-box?
Try removing private set and check.

Comment: Your code show that `SerialData` is not initialized to an object, so it's **null** !!

Comment: Check the output window for System.Data errors or the the XAML binding failures window, make sure all relevant fields and props are instantiated, especially `m_dataCollector` and `SerialData`

Comment: @G K I removed the private, but no change

Comment: @Ibram Reda SerialData is initialized in the constructor, I just added snippets of code

Comment: @lidqy I checked for binding errors, and there were none

Comment: If you check that there is no Binding Errors "**At Run Time**" ... check the logical tree if it has the elements there .... sometimes the text color is same to the background color, so you don't see it .... or try to recreate the problem in separate  project and upload it to GitHub and share it to get a more help

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for not seeing the collection data.
One possibility is a missing notification.

If you assign a value to the SerialData collection after the initial XAML loading routines have finished, your view won't notice that you've set `SerialData` later on.

You need to raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` in the setter to notify the view of the property change.

```
class DataCollector : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    ...
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    ...
    private ObservableCollection<SerialMessage> _serialData;
    ....
    //somewhere some line code assigns to SerialData

    SerialData = GetSerialData();

    /// <summary>
    /// All of the Data recived on the serial Bus as it comes in
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<SerialMessage> SerialData
    {
        get => _serialData;
        private set {
           if (value != _serialData)
           {
                _serialData = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventsArgs(nameof (SerialData)));
           }
    }
```

Comment: I tried adding the InotifyPropertyChanged, and this did not make a difference